# Implementing a Arraylist-based Bag/Multiset- stuck on generics

Tags: java, generics, data-structures

An assignment has asked us to implement a Bag data type using either ArrayList or LinkedList as the backend.  I've picked the ArrayList and created my own implementation of it, including local implementations of the Collection interface.  Now I'm struggling with the basic concept of how to adapt the properties of a Bag using the my List class, specifically inserting a List within a List.

The way my List is set up follows the usual Java type, except all the methods aren't implemented, which is why I wrote my own Collection interface type as

```
public interface Collection<E>
```

implementing add, remove, size, clear, contains, isEmpty and toArray methods.

The List type is declared as

```
public class List<E> implements Collection<E>
```

with three private fields:

```
private int size;
private E[] data;
private int growSize=10;
```

the `E[] data` holds whatever element type is needed, and growSize is the number of new slots to increase the list size as needed. This works great when the List is used traditionally for single objects, but I get errors when I try to insert a List type.

I'm trying to implement this method:

```
public boolean add(Collection<E> c){
  if (size < data.length){
    data= (E[]) new Object[10];
    data[0]= c;
  }
}
```

When I try this, it says there's a type mismatch between Collection and E.

Two questions:

- First, what rules of Java generics am I breaking here and why?
- Second, what is needed to fix it?

Comment: Give more information about your error and code that causes it, please

Comment: E can be of type List<?>.  What error are you getting?

Comment: what does `add` do? add a single element? or add all elements from some collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a parameterized-type for two different types. In your case (if I get you), you're trying to use the parameterized-type `E` for both type `E` itself and type `Collection<E>`.

If you're trying to have these two different types in your `List<E>`, you actually have no use in Generics. You can just declare your List (and the supertype Collection) without it.

If you're trying to accept a list of objects of type E, and add each of them one-by-one to your `List<E>`,so that each such object of type `E` will become an element in your List, then you should change the implementation to something like:

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<E> c) { 
  for( E e : c ) {
     this.add(e);
  }
}
```